# where can I find the iOS drawables?

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS programming. On Android we can use the platform icons, like the ones shown on Android Asset Studio:

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Is there a place where I can find the platform specific iOS icons? Are they somewhere in the sdk?

I am talking about platform specific icons, like in Android there is a standard share icon, battery, wifi, rotation lock, etc. Is there such a thing for iOS? Does Apple provide icons that we can use inside our app, like a pause button, share, etc?

Comment: Be more specific. What exactly are you looking for and how do you plan to use them?

Comment: iOS don't provide system pictures, but system view. you can get the system icon when use system button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using sketch app for mac os with this template: http://www.sketchappsources.com/free-source/281-ios7-icons-natives-and-basics.html .
I don't know if its useful for you.